# How does MPEG-DASH implement authorization?

Tags: video-streaming, live-streaming, mpeg, mpeg-dash

i unable to find how MPEG-DASH secure's stream from others.

For example: I have WebSite with basic authorization (username/password). 
Each user log in with his credentials.
Server streams 10 different videos.

**Quoestions:**

1. If it possible to let specific user to see specific video?
2. Does MPEG-DASH lib include authorization?
3. Do i need to write my own authentications?

If there's any tutorial, or documentary please post it :) Thanks

Comment: You should read about DRM for example [here](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?580-How-to-secure-MPEG-DASH-streaming-using-Common-Encryption-(CENC)) or [here](http://www.dash-player.com/blog/2015/06/replacing-flash-adaptive-streaming-and-drm-in-html5/). Using HTML5 you can rely on EME I guess.

Comment: @incBrain Thanks,  for fast replay, but It's encryption, not authorization.

Comment: Oh, sry. I know that ISO/IEC 23009 Part 4 I think, deals with Encryption and Authentication, since its coupled with Authorization maybe reading the standard will help.

Comment: @incBrain I have looked, as i understood, in quoestion: 2 answer: No, 3 answer: Yes . Do you approve?

Comment: I would say, 1 - Yes, 2 - Not sure (I'm a little bit confused about the word "lib" ) 3 - I would say Yes.

Comment: In context of 2. - If you refer to a player implementation with "lib", it of course depends. The implementation from https://www.bitmovin.com/ can be used with AWS (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html) for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MPEG-DASH is concerned really with streaming the video, audio, subtitles etc from a server to end users.

There is generally a separate 'catalogue' like function on the server side which decides what a user can and can't see is available to be streamed. This view can be dependent on the particular user, using a standard user login and session mechanism.

In addition to this you may want to encrypt your video using DRM. If you do this the client playing the video has to request a licence key from a 'Licence Authority' server.

The LA server can also require that users have logged in or authorised themselves for your service, hence you can make sure that only a given user is allowed view a particular video (even if they somehow discover the URL for one the catalogue function has not presented to them). Again, this mechanism is independent from MPEG-DASH itself, except that the MPEG-DASH manifest file may contain the URL for the LA server (this depends on the DRM system in use).